# Code seems to not be iterating correctly, I am getting too few outputs

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, openpyxl, nested-loops

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd

# Open Excel Workbook that contains all the requested kinases and ligands
wrkbk = openpyxl.load_workbook("Python Source Doc.xlsx")
sh = wrkbk.active

wrkbk2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Kinase Data.xlsx')
sh2 = wrkbk2.active

wrkbk3 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Drug Data.xlsx')
sh3 = wrkbk3.active

#while True:
for i in range(2, sh2.max_row+1):
    pdb = sh2.cell(row=i, column=9).value
    kinase_group = sh2.cell(row=i, column=3).value
    kinase_family = sh2.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    kinase_name = sh2.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    for i in range(2, sh3.max_row+1):
        if pdb == sh3.cell(row=i, column=3).value:
            drug_name = sh3.cell(row=i, column=1).value
            cell = sh.cell(row=i, column=1)
            cell.value = kinase_group
            cell = sh.cell(row=i, column=2)
            cell.value = kinase_family
            cell = sh.cell(row=i, column=3)
            cell.value = kinase_name
            cell = sh.cell(row=i, column=4)
            cell.value = drug_name
            cell = sh.cell(row=i, column=5)
            cell.value = pdb

wrkbk.save('Python Source Doc.xlsx')
```

The code should iterate through the list of kinase data, pull out the pdb ID and some other information, then iterate through the Drug Data and find the name of the drug that matches that ID and print information to another excel sheet.  There are 12,000 rows in the kinase data sheet and I only get 200 rows in the output which is impossibly small.
Am I missing something, what can I change to make it work properly?

Comment: It's really confusing that you're using the same variable `i` in both loops. Maybe it's even related to the problem.

Comment: You're also using `i` as the index into `sh` rows. Is it supposed to be the same row as `sh2` or `sh3`?

Comment: In this case using `i` as the count for both loops may not be causing a problem searching and extracting the data from from `'Drug Data.xlsx'`. However it is **extremely bad practice** to do this. More so when you are asking others to look at your code and try to make sense of it. You should make everything, variable names included, as clear as possible to help others understand the purpose for each line.

Comment: It seems you will however end up with blank lines in `'Python Source Doc.xlsx'` for each `pdb ID` in `'Kinase Data.xlsx'` that is not found in `'Drug Data.xlsx'` as a result of using `i` as the row variable for all sheets, but otherwise with the information provided the code appears it would work.

Comment: I'll just also note a significant inefficiency in the search. The code searches 'Drug Data.xlsx' from row 2 for a match, writes the values to `"Python Source Doc.xlsx"` then goes back and continues on with the search of `'Drug Data.xlsx'` to the end. So for every `pd ID` in `'Kinase Data.xlsx'` the code searches all 12,000 rows of `'Drug Data.xlsx'` even if it finds the ID in row 2. You should `break` the loop once the details are found and written.

Comment: You should try and do this without nested loops. Also, I'd advise against using `pdb` as a variable name, just in case you ever want to work with the `pdb` module.